# Regex and angle brackets

Tags: regex, nginx

I have the following regular expression on nginx:

```
^(?<subdomain>.+)\.test\.com$
```

If parenthesis are for group, then how does it matches 'something.test.com', or 'foobar.test.com' ?
I was expecting to match something that only the word 'subdomain'. I think I am not understanding the ?, and the <> symbols. Also I can't see the use for the .+ at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(?<name>.+)` is a named capture group. The only pattern part of this group is the `.+`

The benefit to using named capture groups is that you can reference them by name rather than number, so in this case "something" or "foobar" can be referenced using the subdomain capture group.

The `.+` at the end just means to match one or more of any character *except* newline characters.

[This should help you visualize it better](https://regex101.com/r/ekemsW/6)

Comment: Is is an nginx feature, or perl feature? I am wondering if this is an nginx feature (so you can use then 'something' or 'foobar' as a variable), why you don't escape the ? and <> symbols.

Comment: This is just a regex feature. You don't escape them because they aren't part of your pattern, `(?<...>...)` is just syntax for a named capture group, if you escape those symbols, not only will it break your syntax, but you'll then be searching for whichever characters you escape in addition to the rest of your pattern.